# Подскажите, на какой программе написаны Torrent, Chrome, Opera

Tags: c#, wpf, windowsinstaller

А то я пишу в microsoft visual studio 2013 на wpf и никак не могу избавиться от .net framework.

Например

Инсталляция проекта с помощью smart install maker получается как в любой программе.

Но когда запускаю через ярлык пробует .net framework. Прикол в том, что ни одна программа не инсталлирует .net framework, но они все запускаются.

Подскажите, как мне запустить без .net framework, пожалуйста.

Comment: Костику, ви зовсiм-зовсiм не можете росiйською?

Comment: Пишите, пожалуйста, по-русски. ru.stackoverflow - это русскоязычный проект.

Comment: Перевёл в силу своих знаний языка. Смысл не менял.

Comment: C# и WPF требуют .NET Framework, вы от него избавиться не сможете.

Comment: Если вы хотите нетривиальный UI, WPF — хороший выбор. Инсталляторы по идее должны уметь не тащить за собой .NET redist.

Comment: А браузеры и прочее написаны на чистом C++. У каждого наверняка свой UI-фреймворк. У Opera скорее всего Qt.

Comment: Я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса как не соответствующего теме, потому что автор проигнорировал языковый мейнстрим, закреплённый в т.ч. и соответствующим правилом данного ресурса.

Answer (score 6):

Chrome и Opera основаны на одном движке - [chromium](https://www.chromium.org/Home). Который написан на С++. Но это не существенно, потому что любая крупная программа тянет за собой багаж. При этом WPF имеет преимущество, ведь, как правило, весь необходимый ей багаж уже есть в системе. А если нет, то включить .net framework в установщик не составляет труда.

Одним из наиболее популярных фреймворков для написания графических приложений в C++ является Qt, который надо с собой тащить в установщике. И весит Qt не мало. Поэтому, в этом плане, это решение ничем не лучше .net framework(а в сущности намного хуже - Qt за собой тащит каждое приложение).

Единственный способ не тащить за собой вообще ничего, это писать на языке платформы с использованием соответствующего API:

- Windows: C/C++: Win32 API или MFC+ATL+WTL(это абстракции над Win32 API) - ужасный выбор
- Windows 8+(приложения для Windows Store): XAML + C#/C++(CX) или HTML+Javascript: Windows Runtime - хорошо, но пока недостаточно, т.к. куча ограничений, да и аудитория не та, что у обычных приложений
- Linux: C\C++ - Xlib(хотя тут уже можно использовать Qt, т.к. ситуация с распространением оной на линуксе проще)
- OS X, iOS: Objective C++(Swift?): Carbon/Cocoa

В общем, на мой взгляд, если в качестве платформы нужен только windows и приложение не имеет очень строгих требований к производительности, тогда нечего морочить голову - просто пишите с использованием WPF, получите куда меньше проблема, чем с любым другим решением.

Comment: Программы на Delphi не тяну за собой никаких библиотек, если вы их сами отдельно не добавляете. Т.е. штатно, из коробки вся программа с GUI и другими вещами будет представлять из себя исключительно один exe/apk/app/linux app файл и не требовать дополнительного рантайма.

И не важно, какого масштаба программа